# Insert data in to 4 endpoints via one request api in fileupload feature loopback4

Tags: file-upload, multer, loopback4, angular-loopback

I have uploaded the files using multer disk storage in loopback ,those details i want  to create the entries in  4 different tables via one api request .Could you please tell me how we can achieve this ,Pls share if you any reference links ,Thank you

I dont how to do that , could you please tell me the way or share me any reference links

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using multiple repositories in one request like this:

```
await this.firstRepository.create(data);
await this.secondRepository.create(data);
this.thirdRepository.create(data);
```